# Styling static Rails HTML using stylesheet assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I am looking to create static error pages (like the 404, 422 and 500 pages given by Rails) which have the same theme as the app does.

The theme of the app is in stylesheets in my assets pipeline. How do I connect to the stylesheets from my static pages?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just trying to this myself and it looks like http://neovintage.blogspot.de/2012/02/precompile-static-html-pages-with-rails.html is a good way to do it.

What it Rimas Silkaitis suggests there is to add an html assets folder (for your error pages) which is then precompiled along with your other assets. This allows you to use ERB and the asset helper functions.

This does not easily work in your development environment though.

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work. Running the rails server locally in production is what I used to test. The ERB doesn't compile.

Comment: I figured out the solution of the problem that @pascal said about development environment. http://blog.kyanny.me/entry/2012/06/14/022834